# Why does Donna keep flipping the face of her wristwatch on meetings?

Tags: halt-and-catch-fire

In season 4 episode 1 Donna is shown to have a special wristwatch the face of which can be flipped. There doesn't seem to be anything of interest on the other side. She is shown to start some meetings with the face up and some with the face down and even flipping it once mid-meeting. What is the significance of her doing that? Is she trying to make a point to others/intimidate or is it some kind of mental note to herself?

Comment: I wondered the same thing. The current answer seems to be the best explanation I've read. But, knowing the set and costume designers' attention to detail, I also wonder if it was a popular watch design back in the mid-90s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> She is shown to start some meetings with the face up and some with the face down and even flipping it once mid-meeting.

My quick review indicates that the watch is flipped only at the start and end of a pitch/funding meeting.

She flips the face side down at the start and back at the end...I did not see any instance of the other version.

She does *start* to flip the watch during a meeting when she thinks it's over but stops when the group's pitch something interesting.

---

As for what it means *to her*, it's not clear but it may be that it indicates that, during such meetings, **time is not important**.

She's not clock-watching, she lets the ideas come in and evaluates them based on her own opinions and feelings and is not bound to some specific time-table.